# removing thousand separator in R

Tags: r

Recently I have had a very strange problem.  I used `write.table` to write data into a tab-delimited text file.  After the command executed, and when I opened the text file, every value had a thousand separator that was not there in R.

For an example, in R I get the following values:

```
 159.234789
 160.678151 
 154.878034
 456.126789
```

After I used `write.table`, these values are in the file:

```
 159.234.789
 160.678.151 
 154.878.034
 456.126.789
```

I don't know what is happening.  Could anyone can help me please.

The command which I use for write.table is given below

```
write.table(dataset,file ="D:/abc_.01.txt",sep="\t",col.names=T,row.names=T)
```

The sessionInfo is given below

```
R version 2.12.2 (2011-02-25)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: What structure are these keept in and what type (character/numeric)? What does options() look like?

Comment: @Thileepan I had thought it might partly have been a locale issue, but it seems the numeric conventions are fixed. The only way I can think to get from one output to another is `format(123.456789*1e6, big.mark=".")`, but it beats me how this can happen.

Comment: You write "when I opened the text file". How do you do this?

Comment: @James Sorry i m not able to get what are trying to say.Is that issue with my system or with command

Comment: @BenBarnes I generally open the tab delim file with excel...previously it was working fine.but very recently it is displaying with thousand seprators

Comment: @Thileepan Neither as far as I can tell. Unless there is something funky with your data (which is unlikely as your don't seem to be using any exotic classes) then its a mystery. Perhaps a restart will solve everything.

Comment: @Thileepan Ah, MyStery solved: its Excel formatting this automatically. Presumably it thinks `.` is your thousands separator and `,` is your decimal separator. You might have more luck using `write.csv2` rather than `write.table`, or add `dec=","` to the `write.table` command.

Comment: Excel is most likely the culprit. It is probably guessing that the decimal points in the text file are thousands separators. Can you use `write.csv2()` to save the file? Or change the `dec` argument in `write.table` to `","`

Comment: @BenBarnes I tried changing the 'dec' argument in 'write.table as ',' but it gives the output as 159,234,673.But the actual value is 159.234673.The original file has was prepared in the German operating system and it had ',' as decimal operator.I read the file using read.delim with 'dec' as ',' and manipulated the data and rewrite the file in tab delim format for other anaylsis

Comment: @James I tried changing the 'dec' argument in 'write.table as ',' but it gives the output as 159,234,673.But the actual value is 159.234673.The original file has was prepared in the German operating system and it had ',' as decimal operator.I read the file using read.delim with 'dec' as ',' and manipulated the data and rewrite the file in tab delim format for other anaylsis

Comment: @Thileepan Did you try `write.csv2`? It was written specifically for Excel in Western European locales.

Comment: @James I tried but the still it is using commas as thousand separators..here is the command I have used.. write.csv(xx,file ="D:/combine/6285449021_A_.01.csv",sep="\t",col.names=TRUE,row.names=TRUE,dec=",")

Comment: This seems to be more of an Excel question than an R question. Open your file in a plain text editor and see if it goes correct there. I am pretty sure that when importing a text file in Excel (or any free alternative) you can just select what the deceminal separator is.

Comment: If you execute `write.table` with `file = ""` (`write.table (dataset,file =""\t",col.names=T,row.names=T)`
you should see what exactly `write.table` outputs. That would help to definitively answer the questions whether the problem is to be solved in R or in Excel. Otherwise: do look with a plain text editor at the file (as suggested by Sascha).

Comment: @SachaEpskamp When I tried to open the file in Plain note pad,it shows the values without thousands separator which is what I want.

Comment: What I thought. Hence your problem is not "how do I remove the thousand seperator in R" but "How do I import this text file in Excel". This is a completely different question that is probably best suited for http://superuser.com/